# Error push back reference to elements of const vector

Tags: c++, vector, constants

Please consider the following:

```
// from main file

// first arguement gets enc_array
Rock rock (voice.getEncArray());
// getEncArray() gets a vector of vectors:
// std::vector<std::vector<unsigned int> > enc_array;

// in rock.hpp file, consider members
Rock( const std::vector<std::vector<unsigned int> > &);

std::vector<std::vector<unsigned int> * > remaining;

const std::vector<std::vector<unsigned int> > * population;

// in rock.cpp
Rock::Rock ( const vector<vector<unsigned int> > & v) :
  population (&v),
  ....

// in one of the class member functions
for ( vector<vector<unsigned int> >::const_iterator ci = population->begin(); ci != population->end(); ++ci ) {
    // for some indexes...
    remaining.push_back (& (*ci));      // <------  PROBLEM
}
```

gcc reports:

```
error: no matching function for call to 'std::vector<std::vector<unsigned int>*>::push_back(const std::vector<unsigned int>*)'

note: void std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::push_back(const value_type&) [with _Tp = std::vector<unsigned int>*; _Alloc = std::allocator<std::vector<unsigned int>*>; std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::value_type = std::vector<unsigned int>*] <near match>

note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from 'const std::vector<unsigned int>*' to 'std::vector<unsigned int>* const&'
```

I understand that I'm trying to push the addresses of `vector<int>` that were considered `const` to a non-const `vector`.
After `remaining` is filled-up, no other method will change its data, so in fact it should be `const`.
But I cannot declare `remaining` as a `const vector`, as it would give an error.

```
error: no matching function for call to 'std::vector<std::vector<unsigned int>*>::push_back(const std::vector<unsigned int>*) const'

note: candidate is:
note: void std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::push_back(const value_type&) [with _Tp = std::vector<unsigned int>*; _Alloc = std::allocator<std::vector<unsigned int>*>; std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::value_type = std::vector<unsigned int>*] <near match>

note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from 'const std::vector<unsigned int>*' to 'std::vector<unsigned int>* const&'
```

Do I really need to copy elements from `population` to `remaining`? Or is there anything else I can do in order not to have this overhead?

Comment: Try `iterator` instead of `const_iterator`.

Comment: @Synxis: Not possible since `population` is defined as `const` (conversion problem...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
std::vector<const std::vector<unsigned int> *> remaining;
```

Answer (score 2):

You are taking the address of an element of `population`, with the possibility to change it later. This is bad, because you specified `population` to be `const`.

You should remove the `const` keyword from the `population` definition, and then use `iterator` instead of `const_iterator`, if you want to change elements of `population`.